# How to step through an Ember promise array?

Tags: ember.js

Please refer to http://emberjs.jsbin.com/volim/1/edit

The display of Categories happens with no problem.  Notice how I have the index template and IndexController set up to display the Categories in a table.  The user will click on a Category to display the Links that the clicked on Category has.

What I am trying to do and failing at is have the link template and the LinkController arrange the links to be displayed in a table, just the the Categories.

When I step through the LinkController code, sometimes it goes into the then callback function and sometimes it does not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: On my phone, and jsbin will yell at you, but you can toss a debugger; inside the then.  (Ignore me if this is useless and I can take a look later on a computer)

Comment: Thanks kingpin2k.  I use WebStorm which lets me debug the Ember code and I still can not figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `pushObject` when you are pushing objects into an array in Ember.  It's the equivalent setter for an array.  The reason the other computed property works is due to the items being pushed into the array before Ember evaluated it.

```
rows: function(){
    var columns = 5;
    var row = [];
    var rows = [];

    this.get('links').then(function(theLinks){

      theLinks.forEach(function(l){
        row.push(l);
        if(row.length === columns){
          rows.pushObject(row);
          row = [];
        }
      });
      if (row.length > 0) {
          rows.pushObject(row);
      }
    });

    return rows;
}.property('links')
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qivebiho/3/edit

Comment: Thanks kingpin2k.  That fixes the problem of the rows showing up in the template.  I discovered one further problem.  When you run the app, which ever category you click on first, that category's links always show up no matter which category you click on after that.  Do you know of a way to tell Ember to re-populate the rows array?

Comment: Yeah, computed properties can watch other properties and be considered dirty when the property changes.  In the example above, watching links would recalculate it.  If you wanted to dynamically add more links, you might watch links.[] which would then update the computed property every time the links collection grew or shrunk.

Comment: Thanks again kingpin2K.  This helps me a lot!